# how to get python command after run via ssh in php

Tags: python, php, ssh

I have to run local python script via PHP ssh connection .
is run okay .
but my python file has this line

```
print ("this_ run _ is good");
```

how I get this message in my PHP page?

Comment: Please clarify and show us what you have tried.

Comment: can you post your PHP code wich run the python script ?

Comment: I think that he wants to modify the page, he would like to display a web page after the run is successfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you want to display a web page if run is ok.
I would suggest Paramiko where command to execute with bash you can create a page

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd_to_execute)
```